# Why is the time complexity of n^2 logn + n(logn)^2 = O(n^2(logn)^2)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Why is the complexity of n^2 logn + n(logn)^2 = O(n^2 (logn)^2) ?
I saw this as a solution to Cornell's Final exam paper (found online) but I'm not too sure if it is correct.

Comment: It is not: O(n² log n + n log² n) = O(n² log n)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your thoughts on why it should be that time complexity and more importantly why it should not, with your own words.

Comment: @norok2 question 6j http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2110/2016sp/Exams/final/finalsolcs211sp07.pdf

Comment: @MingPokNg Looks like a blunder to me

Comment: That looks like a good question to me. It's a trick question, but an interesting one IMHO. It's not a blunder it's made purposely to test wether people understand the principle of an upper bound.

Comment: @cglacet If it is trying to teach the principle of an upper bound, it is also clumsily misplaced. Sure, it is also *O(n³)*, etc. but it is not the way you would normally characterize asymptotic complexity. By the same judgement parameter, any answer in the first question of the exam could have been *O(n^k)* for k >= 1. But that is not normally what one would do. And I hardly believe the teacher would give you credit for such answers, without getting into an argument.

Comment: @norok2 You are right, as is the question is not precise enough and O(n^k) would indeed be a valid answer. On the other hand it's not the best answer (and people should have learn that it's not). So it will depend on wether the teacher loves jokes or not :p. But maybe the correction is wrong and both lower/upper bound were expected, in which case all the answers are only partially correct as they only give the upper bound. The best answer would be to give both bounds and write them as `Θ(…)` when they are the same. The problem here is that there are implicit student/teacher conventions.

Answer (score 2):

The statement n² log n + n (log n)² ∈ O(n² (log n)²) is valid. It's just not the best upper bound one could give on this function. But it's still true. Note that f(n) ∈ O(n² log n) ⇒ f(n) ∈ O(n² (log n)²). That's why people never (or shouldn't) write f(n) = O(g(n)), but should instead write f(n) ∈ O(g(n)).

On the other hand, the provided bound is a bit conservative, it could very well be because n² log n is smaller than n (log n)² for small values of n (n < 1). Or maybe, because it's part of a test, it could also be a way to test wether students fully understood what f(x) ∈ O(g(n)) means (a trick question, but an interesting trick question). Even though I would have added a question right before asking wether the following is a valid statement: is "n² log n + n (log n)² ∈ O(n² (log n))".

The more conservative bound could hypothetically make sense depending on the context (if n is very small and 1 could already be considered a "large value"), but usually if that's the case it would be specified explicitly.

If nothing specifies otherwise, people would assume that the best upper bound for this function is O(n² log n).

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the theory as explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

There it is written that if *f1* is *O(g1)* and *f2* is *O(g2)*, *f1 + f2* is *O(max(g1, g2))*.

Let's consider *f1 = n² log n* and *f2 = n log² n*.
Then *f1* is *O(n² log n)* and *f2* is *O(n log² n)*.

Now, for *n > 1*, since *n > log n*, we can multiply both sides of the inequality by *n log n* to obtain *n² log n > n log² n*. This proves that *O(n² log n) > O(n log² n)* and, by the definition from above we have: *O(n² log n)*.

Comment: Care, log(n) isn't always positive so the proof is a bit "harder" than that (you have to specify that n > 1)

Comment: @cglacet Nitpickingly correct. Nobody cares because we are taking the limit for n -> ∞ anyway. And n is a positive integer for computational complexity calculations. So that pretty much reduces to a single value where this is not strictly true.

Comment: The proof is still not correct, n > log n is always true, the problem arise when you multiply both side of the inequation by log n (which is not always positive). It's would also probably more correct/standard to write "n log² n ∈ O(n² log n)" than "O(n² log n) > O(n log² n)". But honestly if you had to prove this I think stating that "n² log n > n (log n)² for n > 1" is way more than enough.

Comment: for n > 1, log n > 0. Therefore I am failing to see why the multiplication would be a problem.

Comment: For n > 1 there is no "problem", but in general the statement "n² log n > n log² n" isn't valid. In other words it's not "n > log n (for n > 1)" but "n² log n > n log² n  (for n > 1)".